Finding out when someone voted for your question on Stack Exchange
Here is a question I posted on a Stack Exchange website: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404052/why-is-the-traveling-salesperson-problem-difficult
Is it possible to see a complete history of when (timestamp) each upvote and downvote occurred?
For example:
  score           timestamp cumulative_score
    10 2024-07-31 17:21:33               10
   -10 2024-08-01 02:55:01                0
   -10 2024-08-01 05:11:04              -10
   -10 2024-08-01 06:28:40              -20
    10 2024-08-01 07:15:45              -10
   -10 2024-08-01 13:21:15              -20

Can this be done with the Stack Overflow API?
The closest thing I found was this: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4404052/timeline

But this does not contain the full voting history. I do not need to know which users voted - just the times at which the score changed.
References:

Can you see the voting history of a question / answer

Note: The reason I am asking - I am interested in knowing if the intensity at which scores change on a question can be modelled using a random walk (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)

You linked to a version of the timeline where you had hidden the vote summaries. Click the "Show vote summaries" button at the top to get to https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4404052/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

Questions about the operation of [so] should be asked on [meta]

@TangentiallyPerpendicular How to questions about how to code against a public API are on-topic on SO. Stack Apps does take support questions with regards to the Stack Exchange API. (disclosure: I'm a mod on Stack Apps)
